# Monotone Converge Theorem for quasi-increasing sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I want to refer to Exercise 2.6.6 part (c) of Abbot's Analysis book.
Let $(a_n)$ be a quasi-increasing sequence if for all $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exists an $N$ such that whenever $n>m\geq N$ it follows that $a_n>a_m-\varepsilon$. The question is the following: Is there an analogue of the Monotone Convergence Theorem for quasi-increasing sequences?

I have tried proving that $(a_n)\rightarrow a$, where $a=supA$ and $A=\{ a_n: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$ or that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence (as suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4024931/having-trouble-proving-quasi-increasing-sequence-proof)). This is what I have so far:

- Let $\varepsilon>0$
- By Axiom of Completeness, let $a=supA$, where $A=\{ a_n: n\in\mathbb{N} \}$
- Since $a$ is the supremum, then $a-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A$. Then there is some $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{N_1}>a-\varepsilon$
- Since $(a_n)$ is quasi-increasing, and $\varepsilon>0$, then there is some $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>m\geq N_2$, then $a_n>a_m-\varepsilon$.
- Let $N=max\{N_1,N_2\}$ be our chosen $N$
- Since we want to prove that $(a_n)$ is Cauchy, then let $n\geq N$ and $m\geq N$. I thought of working with cases.
- Case 1: m>n. Then $m>n\geq N$. Thus, a_m>a_n-\varepsilon, so $-\varepsilon<a_m-a_n$. From here, I don't know how to proceed to get that $a_m-a_n<\varepsilon$.

From here I have tried to prove whether $(a_n)$ converges to $a$ or if $(a_n)$ is Cauchy without luck. I would appreciate any hints or guide on how to proceed with the proof. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can prove that $a$ will be your limit, the fact that $(a_n)$ is quasi-increasing doesn't give any constraint on the first terms of your sequence. Maybe you can do this with the lim sup of $a_n$ instead of the supremum.

Another way to go about it is to notice that, if your sequence is upper-bounded, then it is bounded, therefore, using Weierstrass' theorem, it has a converging subsequence. You can then try proving that $(a_n)$ converges to the limit of this subsequence.

Comment: Any increasing sequence is quasi-increasing. So we cannot prove boundedness.

Comment: In order to prove an equivalent to the Monotone Convergence theorem, I assumed that $(a_n)$ was upper-bounded, and proved convergence, just forgot to specify it, my bad.